# How can I make a character moving forward after first animated walk cycle?

Tags: animation, armature

I created an armature that walks for one cycles. Moves first leg and then second leg and that brings him into start position again. I have also made all animations so he moves forward those two steps. The whole cycle is 10 frames. So far all good. Now I want him to move forward next two steps. How can I do that without having to set each loc-rot manually? There must be som automation for this I hope. There is a lot of bones in the armatur and it would take forever to do this.